# How can I check all results in this code about the extremum of a function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to find three integer numbers, `a, b, m`, so that the function
$$x^3/3 + a (m + 1) x^2/2 + b (m^2 - 5 m) x$$ have $x=2$ is a maximum point of the function. I tried

```
Clear[f, g, k];
    f[x_] := x^3/3 + a (m + 1) x^2/2 + b (m^2 - 5 m) x;
    g[x_] = D[f[x], x];
    d = Discriminant[g[x], x];
    k[x_] = D[f[x], {x, 2}];
    list = {a, b, m} /.
      Solve[{d > 0, g[2] == 0,
        k[2] < 0, -10 <= a <= 10, -10 <= b <= 10, -20 <= m <= 20,
        a b  m != 0}, {a, b, m}, Integers]
```

and get

> {{-10, -9, 1}, {-9, -8, 1}, {-9, 10, 7}, {-8, -10, 3}, {-8, -7,
> 1}, {-7, -6, 1}, {-7, 3, 10}, {-6, -5, 1}, {-5, -6, 3}, {-5, -4,
> 1}, {-4, -9, 4}, {-4, -3, 1}, {-3, -2, 1}, {-2, -4, 4}, {-2, -2,
> 3}, {-2, 1, 9}, {-2, 2, 7}, {-2, 4, 6}, {7, 1, -6}, {7, 1, -3}, {9,
> 1, -11}, {9, 1, -2}}

How can I check all the above results to know it is true or false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sol = Solve[{d > 0, g[2] == 0, 
   k[2] < 0, -10 <= a <= 10, -10 <= b <= 10, -20 <= m <= 20, 
   a b m != 0}, {a, b, m}, Integers]
And @@ Flatten[{d > 0, g[2] == 0, 
    k[2] < 0, -10 <= a <= 10, -10 <= b <= 10, -20 <= m <= 20, 
    a b m != 0} /. sol, 1]
```

> `True`.

```
Plot[f[x] /. sol // Evaluate, {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, Mesh -> {{2}}, 
 MeshStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[5]]
```

[image]

- Another way is

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] = x^3/3 + a (m + 1) x^2/2 + b (m^2 - 5 m) x;
sol = Solve[{f'[2] == 0, 
   f''[2] < 0, -10 <= a <= 10, -10 <= b <= 10, -20 <= m <= 20}, 
  Integers]
{f'[2] == 0, 
  f''[2] < 0, -10 <= a <= 10, -10 <= b <= 10, -20 <= m <= 20} /. sol
```

[image]